# Method overloading

Tags: java, overloading

I was wondering if you can suggest something here.

I would like to have 2 methods:

```
doSomething(List<Data>) and
doSomething(List<Double>)
```

Since type of parameter is the same, Java is complaining

Is there a way to somehow make this overloading happen?

Comment: @Tom: In your comments you say things like "it could be implemented keeping erasure" but I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean we *can* overload methods in that way with the existing Sun compiler, or do you mean that the compiler could be fixed to allow this? If it's the former, can you explain how? It would be great to be able to do this so if you can show us how we'd all appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void doSomething(List list) {
    if(list.size() > 0) {
        Object obj = list.get(0);
        if(obj instanceof Data) {
           doSomethingData((List<Data>)list);
        } else if (obj instanceof Double) {
           doSomethingDouble((List<Double>)list);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this type-unsafe approach.  You can't assume that the type of every element in the given (raw) list is the same as the type of the first element, which is why the compiler would complain that the casts are unsafe.

Comment: True, but it's also true that this method clearly wouldn't work for types other than Data or Double, therefore I think it's safe to assume its usage is fairly limited.  I think he was looking for a quick alternative.  To be thorough, you'd check the types of all items in the list, but that's grossly inefficient just to be 'safer'.  Better to throw in a comment line or two indicating that it expects lists of type Data or Double.  If precision were so important, you would create doSomethingData and doSomethingDouble.

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, no. Because Java implements generics via erasure those two methods would both compile down to:

```
doSomething(List)
```

Since you cannot have two methods with the same signature this will not compile.

The best you can do is:

```
doSomethingData(List<Data>)
doSomethingDouble(List<Double>)
```

or something equally nasty.

Comment: Since resolution of overloaded methods happens at compile time instead of runtime, in the original (desired) example one presumably knows the type of the elements of the list anyway whenever one of the methods is referenced in the code.  So foregoing overloaded method names in favor of distinct method names isn't that big of a price to pay.

Comment: @Bobby Eickhoff Indeed it is a compile-time issue. Which means that it could be implemented without erasure, so the answer is nonsense.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - Implemented "without erasure"?  Perhaps you mean without generics?

Comment: @Bobby Eickhoff  Er, "without reification"/"regardless of erasure".

Comment: @Tom: Er...it's not nonsense, it answers the OPs question "Is there a way to somehow make this overloading happen?". There is no way to do exactly what the OP wants but this is a suitable workaround. Java does **not** do the kind of cleverness you're talking about at compile time. Maybe it should, maybe it shouldn't, be the fact is that it *doesn't*.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner As far as I can work out, the answer is claiming that erasure prevents the overloading. The answer is wrong.

Comment: @Tom: If it's not erasure, then *why* can't you have `foo(List<A>)` and `foo(List<B>)`?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline: So I just tried compiling this myself. Here's the error message: "Test.java:4: name clash: doSomething(java.util.List<java.lang.String>) and doSomething(java.util.List<java.lang.Double>) have the same erasure". Is it **really** not erasure that's the problem? (Obviously I've changed `Data` to `String` for my test.)

Comment: @Cameron Skinner You can't have that because the Java Language Specification does not allow it. I believe it would actually be a little tricky to specify with the full power of generics. If someone was to implement it, they wouldn't need reification.

Comment: @Tom: Wait, what? I can't have what? If someone was to implement what? I'm not sure if you're talking about what the OP wants or my answer. All I said was that erasure is the problem and you said I'm wrong. I still don't understand why you think I'm wrong - the fact that erasure is used is the fundamental reason why the spec disallows what the OP wants, right?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just name them differently:

```
doSomethingDouble(List<Double> doubles);
doSomethingData(List<Data> data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generics are only available to the compiler, at compile time. They are not  an execution time construct, as such the two methods above are identical, as at runtime both are equivalent too **doSomething(List)**.

Comment: Overload resolution is not a runtime issue!

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't work because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). One thing you could do is to add a dummy parameter, like so:

```
doSomething(List<Data>, Data)
doSomething(List<Double>, Double)
```

Ugly, but it works.

As an alternative, you could give the methods different names.

Comment: it could be implemented keeping erasure - it's a *compile-time* issue.